QUARTO does not find python
I am using quarto in vscode.
When I run quarto check, the output is:
Unable to locate an installed version of Python 3.
Install Python 3 from https://www.python.org/downloads/

However, when I open any *.py vscode detects my python.
I installed python from windows store. Python is installed in this folder:
C:\Users\usuario\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0
How I can configure QUARTO to solve this problem?

That's probably your issue, I'm assuming windows store isn't particularly good for python since it's sandboxed. Just try using the actual python installer from the link its given you.

You can explicitly set the Python path in the Quarto configuration
Open or create a _quarto.yml file in your project directory
and add this configuration:
execute:
  python: "path to python.exe"

Worked for me once

It does not work for me

The solution was to uninstall the Python downloaded from the Windows Store and reinstall it from https://www.python.org/downloads/.
Thanks @Peter

It seems that the issue occurs when you installed Python via the Windows Store. (I had came across the similar issue before with the Windows Store version of Python.) The Windows Store version of Python typically adds the python and pip executables to the system PATH by default. However, it doesn't automatically add the PATH for installed libraries by pip.
To resolve this, you should add the following directory to your system PATH:
C:\Users\******\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\Scripts
This should help with accessing the libraries installed by pip.

this issue may be due to an environment variable. You can try uninstalling python and then reinstalling python from the Windows Store. When installing, check Add python.exe to PATH in the bottom left corner.

